# Spring webservices enpoing and mapping

Tags: java, web-services, spring

I am trying to use AbstractFaultCreatingValidatingMarshallingPayloadEndpoint and find an apropriate endpoing mapping. I can use "PayloadRootQNameEndpointMapping" but my requirement is I need to have a common end point for all my different requests. namespace of the request woudl vary dynamically and I want use the same endpoint to handle all the different request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to figure out this :)

```
<bean id="endpointMapping"
    class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.UriEndpointMapping">
    <property name="defaultEndpoint" ref="myServiceEndpoint"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to add request code in your request ?

then processed your request based on you request code

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I figured out this,I used the UriEndpointMapping